# Validate multiple checkbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I want to validate multiple checkbox to "select atleast one"
view:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="type_one" class="r_type" id="one" value="PA">one</label>
<label> 
<input type="checkbox" name="type_two" class="r_type" id="two" value="FA">two</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="type_three" class="r_type" id="three" value="MA">three</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="type_four" class="r_type" id="four" value="AD">four</label>
```

Model:

```
validate :atleast_one_is_checked

  def atleast_one_is_checked
    errors.add(:base, "Select atleast one output format type") unless type_one || type_two || type_three || type_four
  end
```

I got `undefined method or variable "type_one" error`.

Comment: is `type_one`, `type_two`.. attributes in your database table? If not then how are you storing them?

Comment: Store all checkbox value in one column(type).

Comment: how do you store them?

Comment: So just add `validates_presence_of :attribute_name, message: "Select atleast one output format type"` which will do what you needed.

Comment: I store all four value by "," separated. If nothing selected means it stores ",,,". If i add validates_presence_of :attribute_name it does not show error.

Comment: Instead of `type_one` do `self.type_one` if you have this column in your table

Comment: Use only one field instead of using multiples then it will be easy to validate the field